# Supremum and infimum of a set

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

I wanted to check my reasoning for the following question:

> Determine minimum, maximum, supremum and infimum of the set:
>   $$B=\left\{ -\frac{1}{n} \in \mathbb{Q}: n \in \mathbb{N}_+ \right\}$$

Whenever $n=1$ we have that $-\frac{1}{1}=-1$, this is the minimum element of the set, since  for all $n$ we know that $n\geq 1$ and thus $\frac{1}{n} \leq 1$, this gives $- \frac{1}{n} \geq -1 $.  As the value of $n$ gets bigger (we will later define limits), we notice that $-\frac{1}{n}$ will approach zero, but zero is not contained in the set. We realise that $\sup(B)=0$ and summarise:
        $$\min(B)=\inf(B)=-1$$
        $$\sup(B)=0 $$ $\max(B) $ does not exist.

Comment: Your answers are correct.

Comment: Nothing wrong. You could also say that since $0$ is an upper bound for $B$ but all members of $\Bbb R$ that are upper bounds for $B$ belong to [$0,\infty)$..... because if  $r<0$ then  $\exists n\in \Bbb N\,( n> -1/r>0),\,$ so  $\exists n\in \Bbb N\,(r<-1/n\in B). $ Therefore  $0$ is the least  of all the upper bounds for B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct!

---

Indeed, if you feel uncomforatble to work with negative signs, just compute $\inf A$ and $\sup A$ where $A=\{1/n:n \in \Bbb N\}$ and then use $$\sup(-A)=-\inf A\\\inf(-A)=-\sup A$$

Comment: Good one! This is actually a later exercise.